# Export SSRS Report to csv quickly

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have large report with about 125 columns and 10,000 rows. The SQL Server procedure behind the report runs in about 10 seconds. However the report takes 3-4 minutes to show up on the screen. The user would like to export the report to csv. So he is calling the report using a URL with &rs:Format=CSV specified. This is also taking 3-4 minutes. Is there a way to speed up the export to csv since no screen rendering is required?

Comment: Have you tested with a newer version?  I don't know if there have been any performance improvements in that scenarios, but 2012 is several versions behind.

Comment: I am actually using 2014. Just edited tag.

Comment: I just tested on my local box with Power BI Report Server (which a later version of SSRS) and it was reasonably fast, less than 20 sec for 10,000 rows and 123 columns, resulting in a 2.4MB CSV file.

Comment: take a look at the execution logs and see which bit is taking the time, that might give you a clue. If it#s data processing time then you might be able to optimise the query especially if it has parameters in an IN clause (e.g. WHERE COuntry in @Country)
`SELECT * FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog e 
    JOIN ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] c on e.ReportID = c.ItemID
    WHERE c.Name = 'MyReportName'`